# jQuery underscore notation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could anybody give me an explanation of the underscore in a jQuery plugin function? I have no idea of what "*_*" means. Example code below:

```
$.fn.bgStretch=function(o){
    this.each(function(){
        var th=$(this),
            data=th.data('bgStretch'),
            _={
                align:'leftTop',
                altCSS:{},
                css:{
                    leftTop:{
                        left:0,
                        right:'auto',
                        top:0,
                        bottom:'auto'
                    },
                    rightTop:{
                        left:'auto',
                        right:0,
                        top:0,
                        bottom:'auto'
                    },
                    leftBottom:{
                        left:0,
                        right:'auto',
                        top:'auto',
                        bottom:0
                    },
                    rightBottom:{
                        left:'auto',
                        right:0,
                        top:'auto',
                        bottom:0
                    }
                },
                preFu:function(){
                    _.img
                        .load(function(){
                            _.checkWidthFu()
                            _.img
```

Comment: This is just a normal variable with a (slightly) weird name, nothing special about it.

Comment: is it using the underscore.js library? http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's all clear now.

Comment: @Paul no, it's being declared and assigned in the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as lanzz commented. This is a variable.
Look at how the varaiables are declared:

```
var th=$(this),
    data=th.data('bgStretch'),
    _={..}
```

Another way to it is:

```
var th=$(this);
var data = th.data('bgStretch');
var _ ={...};
```

It might as well have been called `_someVar`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a [`variable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables)

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or
>   dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9).
>   Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters
>   "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z"
>   (lowercase).